# Change html before rendering to avoid a flicker

Tags: javascript, html

I have code I'd like to run before the page is rendered. For example updating dates from absolute time to relative time or converting raw text (or markdown) to html. If I reload the page several times I can see occasionally there's flickering updating the changes. How do I run the code as it's drawn instead at the end where it needs to redraw everything?

I tried `document.addEventListener('beforeload'` it appears that event is depreciated and no longer supported in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to think about your page lifecycle.

When your page is being loaded, if a `<script>` tag is encountered, it will immediately be executed, and prevent any more content being rendered until that script is complete. [This isn't recommended practice.](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS)

But, to answer your question, you *could* do something like this:

```
<p>Your next reward will be available in <span id="nextRewardTime">3600</span>.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $el = $('#nextRewardTime');
    $el.text(format($el.text());
</script>

<p>Come back soon!</p>
```

Now, immediately after the first `<p>` is downloaded by the browser, it'll hit the `<script>` tag and execute the JS. Only once that is complete will it download the next `<p>` tag ('Come back soon!').

You can't attach an event handler to the Javascript before it's been rendered on the DOM, because... well... it's not on the DOM.

The better way of doing this is to **format the thing correctly on the server in the first place**.

Edit: Also, scattering script tags throughout your page makes your code really unmaintainable!

Comment: I was hoping I could do it on the client since localtime is accessible in JS and not in http headers. I could put it in cookies but it'd be a page load behind

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted this (or the other answer) but it wasn't me

Comment: @acidzombie Unfortunately, if it has to be done client side, there will always be a risk of a delay between the content being downloaded, and the JS executing. How long that delay is depends on wether you wrap your code in a `$(document).ready(...)` or have the JS placed immediately after the element.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `document.readyState` and a self-invoking function:

```
<body>
<script>
    function executeFunction() {
        //do stuff - such as check for anchor tags
        $("a").html('Replaced');
        if (document.readyState === 'loading') executeFunction(); // repeat to ensure all the tags get innerHTML-ed
    }
    (function(){
        if (document.readyState === 'loading') executeFunction();
    })();
</script>
<!-- more HTML --> 
</body>
```

It seems that you want JS to execute as the page is loading. You may also want to try using `uninitialized` as the ready state (which occurs before "loading").

Comment: This appears to be correct but I'm missing a piece. Lets say my code is `$('a').html('Replaced')` how do I get it to run as all the `a` tags are loading? Do I use something like `$(document).on('load', 'a', mycode)`? I just made this up I'm not sure if it's valid

Comment: I'll edit my answer with a "creative" possible approach

Comment: From a performance perspective, this is awful. You'll need to make your function idempotent, and the intention of what this is doing isn't clear, IMO.

Comment: Quick comment. It appears it's really really slow. There's now a full second or so before it updates.

Comment: @DaveSalomon, performance was not mentioned by OP at first. My update was a response to his followup comment. At first I just had the self-invoking function

Comment: This site is ridiculous - no mention of performance at first. I answered the OP's question and was told "This appears to be correct". Then the rules changed and performance was mentioned afterwards in a comment, so I updated my correct answer to try to help, and then the downvotes started. Awful

Comment: @TheOneandOnly A good answer should mention any limitations. It's just feedback bud -- try not to take it so personally.

Comment: My original answer, based on the original post,  didn't have the function calling itself over and over again - see my comment. So no real limitation - just a self-invoking function and use of document.readyState, until the parameters changed.

Comment: I upvoted so you'll be neutral. It appears what I am asking for can't be done